# Animated map using R

Tags: r, leaflet, using

I have 30 years data for 15 stations with average temperature and want to create an animation using r studio (leaflet). I was looking at the some codes but it not working. An explanation on how to create timeseries animation using leaflet in r studio would be helpfull.

```
# install libraray
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)


Temp53Yrs_df <- read.csv("C:/Users/Sownal/Documents/53YearsTemp.csv")
View(Temp53Yrs_df)

#make plots for the points in the map
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = Temp53Yrs_df$lat,
               lng = Temp53Yrs_df$long)


# Add Data for Average Yearly Annual Temperature
 col_pal <- colorNumeric(palette = "viridis",
                    domain = Temp53Yrs_df$X1965, reverse = TRUE)

 #make years plot in the map
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(lat = Temp53Yrs_df$lat,
         lng = Temp53Yrs_df$long,
         color = col_pal(Temp53Yrs_df$X1965),
         radius = 20000,
         fillOpacity = 0.4,
         label =  Temp53Yrs_df$X1965) %>%
  addLegend(Temp53Yrs_df, position = "bottomleft", pal = col_pal, 
values = Temp53Yrs_df$X1965, title = "Average Temperature in Year 
1965")

#make years plot in the map
leaflet() %>%
   addTiles() %>%
  addCircles(lat = Temp53Yrs_df$lat,
         lng = Temp53Yrs_df$long,
         color = col_pal(Temp53Yrs_df$X1966),
         radius = 20000,
         fillOpacity = 0.4,
         label =  Temp53Yrs_df$X1966) %>%
  addLegend(Temp53Yrs_df, position = "bottomleft", pal = col_pal, 
 values = Temp53Yrs_df$X1966, title = "Average Temperature in Year 
1966")

 #make years plot in the map
 leaflet() %>%
   addTiles() %>%
   addCircles(lat = Temp53Yrs_df$lat,
         lng = Temp53Yrs_df$long,
         color = col_pal(Temp53Yrs_df$X1967),
         radius = 20000,
         fillOpacity = 0.4,
         label =  Temp53Yrs_df$X1967) %>%
   addLegend(Temp53Yrs_df, position = "bottomleft", pal = col_pal, 
 values = Temp53Yrs_df$X1967, title = "Average Temperature in Year 
1967")

#make years plot in the map
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
   addCircles(lat = Temp53Yrs_df$lat,
         lng = Temp53Yrs_df$long,
         color = col_pal(Temp53Yrs_df$X1968),
         radius = 20000,
         fillOpacity = 0.4,
         label =  Temp53Yrs_df$X1968) %>%
  addLegend(Temp53Yrs_df, position = "bottomleft", pal = col_pal, 
    values = Temp53Yrs_df$X1968, title = "Average Temperature in Year 
    1968")
```

Sample Data is attached below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7F5e.png)enter image description here

Comment: Hi Shawn and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid your question is too vague to get a good answer here. We need to see a sample of the code and data you have, and where you got stuck. Stack overflow isn't the place to get a broad tutorial on how a particular software feature works. I've had to vote to close the question for that reason. If you can edit your question to include the code you have so far and some sample data, I am happy to rescind this vote.

Comment: The above is code that i have written and now i am stuck in making the codes for the animation of the plots.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problems are the animation plots using leaflet in r. As you may have noticed the maps that is generated by above codes are OK.  I need to just animate. I have very less knowledge of animations using leaflets in r